# http.ResponseWritter from server - How to know if the client received the response

Tags: go, httpresponse

In my project I've got a use case when I send (I'm the server) a response to a hardware (the client) and I would like to revert some changes if the client disconnect from the wifi before reading the response.

```
render.Status(r, http.StatusCreated)
render.Respond(w, r, obj)
```

I do a respond and from this point on I want to check if the response is lost in the wild or found the client.

I've tried to hijacked it:

```
hj, ok := w.(http.Hijacker)
if !ok {
    http.Error(w, "webserver doesn't support hijacking", http.StatusInternalServerError)
    return
}
logs.Println("2")
conn, bufrw, err := hj.Hijack()
if err != nil {
    http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    return
}
err = conn.Close()
if err != nil {
    logs.Println("LOL", err)
}
...
```

But I can't catch anything...
I've tried to check the w.Write() err without success!

Any idea on how to proceed?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). In normal HTTP interactions, a properly formatted request is processed regardless of if anybody is listening for a response. Why is receiving a response so critical that not doing so will require reverting the change?

Comment: The only way to know if a message was received is to have the receiver acknowledge the receipt. This goes for most any communication protocol.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn because when the hardware request this endpoint / handler, there are some setup steps with an accessToken returned, but if the response isn't received by the hardware we need to do it all over again

Comment: Then it should probably be up to the client to implement an appropriate timeout and retry policy with exponential backoff.

Comment: @JimB I think I'll use the hijack to expect a "ok" acknowledgement within a 10s timeout. Thanks!

Comment: if it does fail you should log an http 499